# Permutations and 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, c

I want to check if three matrices A,B,C with same dimensions are permutations of each other(contain same elements with the same number of repetitions in every 2d array) and return 1 if they are and 0 if they are not. My code does not work properly; in this case it returns 1 1 1 1 instead of 1 0 1 0. I hope that you could help me with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int permutation (double A[100][100], double B[100][100], double C[100][100], int M, int N){
    int i,j,x,y,true;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            true=1;
            for(x=0;x<M-i && true;x++)
            for(y=0;y<N-j && true;y++)
                if(A[i+x][j+y]!=B[i+x][j+y] || A[i+x][j+y]!=C[i+x][j+y])
                 true=0;
            if(true) return 1;
            }
            return 0;
    }
int main(){
double A[100][100] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
double B[100][100] = { {4, 1, 9}, {7, 8, 3}, {6, 2, 5} };
double C[100][100] = { {8, 4, 6}, {5, 2, 1}, {7, 9, 3} };
printf("%d ", permutation(A, B, C, 3, 3) );


C[2][2] = 1;
printf("%d ", permutation(A, B, C, 3, 3) );


C[1][2] = 3;
printf("%d ", permutation(A, B, C, 3, 3) );


B[2][2] = 10;
printf("%d ", permutation(A, B, C, 3, 3) );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "permutations"? There exist multiple definitions.

Comment: Please note that, since C99, `true` is a macro provided by the header `<stdbool.h>`. It wouldn't be a good idea to use it as a variable name.

Comment: You should be creating a histogram of values for each matrix, and then compare the histograms.

Comment: It looks like your current logic will compare way outside of your boundaries (e.g. i+x could be up to 2M-1 in your inner loop).

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=M;i++)` iterates 4 times.  Did you only want 3 iterations?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited this to remove my first attempt which worked for this particular example, but did not work in general (as pointed out in the comments, thanks). I will leave my second option.

My preferred solution is quite different than what you're currently doing so it might not be what you want, but in general I like the idea of simply sorting and doing a straight comparison.

```
// A comparison function to work with qsort from stdlib.h
// Like the original code, this checks for actual inequality, but when dealing with doubles you might want to look into using DBL_EPSILON from float.h
int doublecomp(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
 double d1 = *(double *)v1;
 double d2 = *(double *)v2;
 if (d1 > d2) {
  return 1;
 }
 if (d1 < d2) {
  return -1;
 }
 return 0;
}

int permutation (double A[100][100], double B[100][100], double C[100][100], int M, int N) {
 double ap[M*N]; // Assuming you have room on the stack for these. If M and N are expected to be large, put this on the heap instead
 double bp[M*N];
 double cp[M*N];
 for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
  memcpy(ap + i * N, A[i], N * sizeof(ap[0]));
  memcpy(bp + i * N, B[i], N * sizeof(bp[0]));
  memcpy(cp + i * N, C[i], N * sizeof(cp[0]));
 }
 qsort(ap, M*N, sizeof(ap[0]), doublecomp);
 qsort(bp, M*N, sizeof(bp[0]), doublecomp);
 qsort(cp, M*N, sizeof(cp[0]), doublecomp);
 return !(memcmp(ap, bp, M*N*sizeof(ap[0])) || memcmp(ap, cp, M*N*sizeof(ap[0])));
}
```

I find this nice to read. It handles arbitrary double values (you can adjust the comparison function based on your actual requirements, e.g. use `DBL_EPSILON`). And, assuming you might possibly have arbitrary doubles, this is probably as efficient as building some mapping for a histogram.

Comment: Yep, making copies and sorting will definitely work, and takes O(nlogn) time (defining `n` to be the number of used entries in one matrix). The histogram solution takes O(n) time (which is debatable IMO, but the academics insist that hash tables are O(1) insertion and lookup). On the other hand, the first snippet definitely doesn't work. Simple example: A={2,3,3} and  B={2,2,3}.

Comment: @EdmCoff The first solution doesn't work when there is a repetition of elements

Comment: Thank you both for correcting me. I have removed the incorrect first solution. I also appreciate the correction about the actual efficiency... I think I still like this because it's easy to understand, easy to implement, and mostly uses built-in functions, but depending on the size of the arrays, OP should consider a histogram.

Comment: @EdmCoff I try to avoid using built-in functions, so that is why I tried to go through your first code. Is there any way to correct your first code to work properly?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid built-in functions, I hope this is for learning or school. It's (usually) bad to not use built-ins otherwise. I don't think the basic idea of the first attempt (or your original attempt) is going to work. You are going to need to know the counts, which will require either storing them or adding additional loops.

Comment: Also, the second solution will work fine without built-ins. You could write your own sort and comparison functions, although at that point there's probably no reason not to just store the counts in a mapping of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could start by defining a function comparing the frequencies of the integers from two matrices.

```c
bool is_permutation(int m1[][NUM_COLS], int m2[][NUM_COLS], int n)
{
    int i, j, num1, num2;
    int m1_counts[MAX_NUM] = {0};
    int m2_counts[MAX_NUM] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            num1 = m1[i][j];
            num2 = m2[i][j];
            if (0 <= num1 && num1 < MAX_NUM &&
                0 <= num2 && num2 < MAX_NUM) {
                    m1_counts[num1]++;
                    m2_counts[num2]++;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: out of bounds");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
        if (m1_counts[i] != m2_counts[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

2. Using this approach you have a choice of either extending the function to include more matrices in its parameters.  A simpler, yet less performant approach would be to just combine the results of multiple comparisons, which can be done with a macro.

```
#define ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, n) \
    (is_permutation((m1), (m2), (n)) && \
     is_permutation((m1), (m3), (n)) && \
     is_permutation((m2), (m3), (n)))
```

3. Printing the results can be handled in a similar way.

```
#define PRINT_ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, n)              \
    printf(#m1 ", " #m2 ", and " #m3 " %s permutations\n", \
        ARE_PERMUTATIONS((m1), (m2), (m3), (n)) ?          \
        "are" : "are not")
```

4. All that need be added to the main function are the following lines.

```
    PRINT_ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, NUM_COLS);

    m3[2][2] = 1;
    PRINT_ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, NUM_COLS);

    m3[1][2] = 3;
    PRINT_ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, NUM_COLS);

    m2[2][2] = 10;
    PRINT_ARE_PERMUTATIONS(m1, m2, m3, NUM_COLS);
```

Comment: You limited num1 and num2 to be between 0 and max, but there is no limit when it comes to the elements in a 2d array,only its size is limited to 100

Comment: Yeah, not the most generalizable solution.  It assumes an array size on the order of the elements that you put in your example (i.e. ~10), which means you would need to redefine the macro and recompile if you wanted to alter the range of possible inputs.  I suppose you could find the maximum element in each matrix before allocating an array to record frequency counts, but I was leaning towards something that would demonstrate the direction you could go, not necessarily robustness.